# CSRF Token Needed?

Tags: php, csrf, contact-form, csrf-protection

Ok, still trying to wrap my head around what they are, and needed for ..believe me I've read plenty on it and *think* I understand but I probably don't ...

The closest I can get is that they're *definitely* needed when you have log-in pages in any form on your site ...

My question is when you have basic contact form and/or fill-in form for any reason ... do you need CSRF tokens for those pages?

Comment: yes - can do no harm as they help protect against mass abuse as contact forms, forums etc are great targets for spammers so having a csrf token checking mechanism is all to the good

Comment: Maybe this is off-topic. To protect a contact form from someone trying to abuse the REST API endpoint with Post man (or any other REST API client), implementing re-captcha on front-end and re-captcha middleware on back-end can be a solution too. CSRF can be a solution, though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSRF tokens are not *'definitely needed'* (as in, forms will work without them) but they are an **extremely good idea** whenever submitting any data from one webpage, to another webpage/script. There is remarkably little way of ***trusting*** that any data `page 2` receives came from `page 1` (read illustration below). Each page in isolations has no idea what page the user was on before, and even things that are intended to hint at this such as `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can be easily manipulated by browser users.

**CSRF** tokens are a page-to-page key giving the receiving page a much higher level of trust that the visitor came from the intended sender page(s).  Deployed property they also can prevent data repetition which is also a big bonus and cuts down on unscrupulous spam and wasted CPU cycles.

---

**One aspect that CSRF tokens can be used for:**

Assume you have a form on a page, the page is called `page1.php` and the form is a `send contact email`, where the form is filled in and then sent, the page it's sent to (page2.php) can build and then send a contact email to the intended recipient.

From this the next step is someone can read the source code of the `page1.php` form. this is trivially easy and tells people what `$_POST` values exist and the location of the destination the form is sent to (`page2.php`).

A simple user will load your `page1.php` , spend ten minutes writing a carefully worded email before pressing the *SEND* button and submitting the form. Off the form goes to the `page2.php` which builds its details into an email sent to `receiver@email.com`.

Now, if someone takes the source code from `page1.php` they can use a simple PHP script (or any other code) processing to send hundreds or thousands of spam forms to `page2.php` , each of them with the correct details to generate and send out an email, this can be used for various nafarious processes, they can send forms from numerous other websites, any other parts of the internet or even from entire botnets if they choose to -- `page2.php` would be inundated with many requests a second and the receiver of the emails will have a mailbox jammed full of useless form-generated messages.

**Enter CSRF token**

A CSRF token is a unique key that is saved in the form, upon generation on `page1.php` and would typically (but not exclusively) use (possibly randomly) generated `$_SESSION` values so that when the form is submitted, and the `$_POST` data is sent to `page2.php` this is a fairly reliable check that the form is being submitted *from the same website*. So instead of having whole botnets submitting data to `page2.php` and causing many emails, the data is not being acted upon and instead only pages submitted from the same website are being run in the `page2.php` script.

Alternaitvely if the above situation where to occur you can also track where bad submissions are coming from and use other processes / scripts to block / ban various other botnets / servers from submitting data to your server.

---

The above illustration is a form of insurance and process control so you have a strong reliablility that data that passes through a CSRF on `page2.php`:

```
 if ($_SESSION['key'] === $_POST['key']){
     unset($_SESSION['key']);   ///prevent repetition
      ...
      send email
    }
```

(for example).

This `if` statement only runs with form data that's been reliably submitted from a reliable source (`page1.php`). Thus preventig other servers piggybacking on your scripts, preventing crass attempts at DOS attacks overloading your `page2.php` as well as various other positives from knowing that `page1.php` sent the data that is being used on `page2.php`.

**Another aspect CSRF tokens are used for**

See in the code above I unset the `$_SESSION` CSRF value? This means that if you press F5 or otherwise refresh the `page2.php` visit (typing it into your browser or whatever) *it will not resubmit the genuine data twice*. This can help prevent people filling in a form once and then constantly resubmitting it like an angry teenager on a forum (*POST data is always saved in the page HTTP header and resubmitted when the page is called, so unsetting `$_POST` data in PHP is pointless.* ).

---

> **CSRF is a security mechanism that - when the CSRF token test is passed -  means you can reliably judge that data sent to a script on your server came from a valid and intended source.**

Comment: wow. thank you so much for taking the time to write out this thoughtful and through answer. it is very much appreciated. i do have a question based on what you said ... if you don't mind =) ... if my form, i.e., `page1.php` is going straight to the `PHPMailer` page instead of `page2.php` ... does that change the need for checking the fact that it was submitted from the same site? btw, I like your funny analogy of angry teenager on forum ... =) .... though who's to say that they're only teenagers? =)

Comment: `page2.php` is the same as the PHPMailer page, it's a resulting page which does whatever you want, `page2.php` can be any page, doing any thing. It doesn't need to be an output HTML page, simply a page which handles the data sent to it by `page1.php`. Before you send anything to PHPMailer object it's intended you run the `if` statement to check the validity of the sent data.